# Merged PDFs Blank

Tags: pdf, batch-file, merge, ghostscript

Trying to merge all pdfs in a directory using GhostScript 9.06 64bit in a .bat file

The following, makes merged.pdf, but it is 1 page and blank

```
call gswin64c -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=merged.pdf *.pdf
```

If I actually specify which PDFs to merge it works fine. What gives?

```
call gswin64c -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=merged.pdf 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specify wildcards on the Ghostscript command line, simple as that.

Since GS didn't find a file called '*.pdf' it didn't execute any marking operations, in this case you get a blank file.

Comment: So I take it these sites are all just wrong? http://www.bsdnexus.com/blog/tag/ghostscript

Comment: There has to be an easy way to do this. I simply cannot phantom anyone specifying the names of all the PDFs to merge.

Comment: Yes, all these sites are wrong, Ghostscript *DOES NOT* process command shell wildcards in Windows (note the site you reference is describing behaviour in Linux). I'm sorry you find this hard to believe but it is the case. Although when I try the same thing here I actually get an error 'undefinedfilename'. Probably you do too but didn't choose to mention it ?

Comment: I wasn't at all saying I find it hard to believe. I was just confirming those sites were wrong or as you said in Linux. Thanks for the confirmation. What I find hard to believe is that there is no way to loop through the file names, much like for %%f in (*.pdf), but combine rather than convert.

Answer (score 1):

Ghostscript cannot do wildcard expansions by itself.

If you call `gs ... *.pdf` from inside a shell which can do wildcard expansion, it will work nevertheless.

There is a difference with the site you linked to and the code you used above:

1. Your code is DOS batch and uses `call gswin64c ...`. But as said, Ghostscript cannnot expand wildcards itself.
2. The code in the linked web page is Unix shell, which does the wildcard expansion *before* Ghostscript gets to see its own commandline. When Ghostscript gets to see it, the wildcard expansion has happened already.

You have to find a solution for your batch file where you first store your (expanded) *.pdf file names in a variable `%mypdfs%` and then do `call gswin64c ... %mypdfs%`.

Comment: See I thought something like this would work, but it just seems to override the merged file, so you end up with a pdf with only the last .pdf in the variable. `for %%f in (*.pdf) do call gswin64c -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=merged.pdf "%%~nf.pdf"`

Comment: I got it to work using two .cmd files [like this](http://www.rgagnon.com/gp/gp-0015.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can't specify the wildcard from the command line, but you can make `gswin32c` run a command file.

as the 'command file' just requires switches to be separated by any amount of white space (space, tab, line break), and there is no limit on the size of the file, we can make a file that does what you need

```
echo -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=merged.pdf > files.gsx
dir *.pdf /b >> files.gsx
```

once this file **files.gsx** has been created, then you can make your file using

> gswin32c @files.gsx

and all the files will be merged

Comment: Sorry, that gives a undefinedfilename as well.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following to solve this:

1.) `dir /B *.pdf > do.bat`

2.) opened `do.bat` with notepad to replace `\r\n` with spaces

3.) inserted: `c:\Programs\gs\gs9.07\bin\gswin64 -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=merged.pdf` at the beginning

and then executed `do.bat`

Voilà